# How to move files from one folder to another in selenium

Tags: java

I am automating a process wherein I am downloading few files from a website using  Selenium. I want to move the files from downloaded folder to another specific folder. Is it possible to achieve it using Selenium ?

I am new to Selenium. So, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The task is to move the downloaded CSV files from one folder to another. I am not moving files related to selenium from one folder to another..

Answer (score 0):

```
File from_file = new File("D:\\Selenium-WebDriver\\Selenium-Tutorials");

File to_file = new File("D:\\Selenium-WebDriver\\Webdriver-Tutorials");

if (from_file.renameTo(to_file))

System.out.println("Successfully moved file");

else

System.out.println("Error while moving file");
```